# The backup I took with mongodb mongodump is extremely slow

Tags: backup, mongodb, nosql

I am using mongodb 7 community version. And I have a system that inserts a lot of log documents. Since I am using the Mongodb community version, I cannot use the ops manager tool used in Mongodb for backup. I take cold backups with mongodump. Is there a way to take a hot backup in the Mongodb community version? Or I need a way to backup faster than mongodump. I'm waiting for your support